# Що означає канон у поданому контексті?

Tags: значення-слів

На сайті [Наше. Тексти пісень](https://nashe.com.ua/song/2445) знайшла таку пісню «При **каноні** стояв»:

> При **каноні** стояв
>
> І фурт-фурт ладував

Що означає **при каноні**?

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanon) подає такі значення слова **канон**:

> **КАНО́Н**, у, чол.
>
> 1. церк. Правило чи догмат із питань віри або виконання релігійних обрядів і т. ін., установлені найвищою церковною владою як закон.
> 2. перен., книжн. Твердо встановлене правило, усталена норма.
> 3. церк. Список, зібрання релігійних книг, узаконених церквою як святе письмо. Старозавітний канон.
> 4. церк. Пісня на честь святого або свята.
> 5. муз. Музична форма, що ґрунтується на повторенні тієї самої мелодії різними голосами хору, які вступають послідовно один за одним.

Але, жодне із цих значень не підходить для вищенаведеного контексту. То що тоді означає **при каноні**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, справді, значення слова канон, що подають у СУМі справді не підходять до поданого Вами контексту. Однак при пошуку слова **канона**, отримуємо таку інформацію:

1. [Словарь української мови в 4-х тт. за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0):

   > **Канона**, ни, ж. ***Пушка***.

> Гей скажи мі, красний улан, ци не тут канони ліпше знають зазвонити, як удома звони. Федьк.

2. [Український тлумачний словник](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/66453/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), посилаючись на Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005:

   > **канона** -и, ж., зах. ***Гармата***.
3. [Словник лемківскої говірки Пиртей П.С., 2001](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/5123/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0):

   > **канона** -ни, ж. Пр. ***Гармата***.

Отже, якщо змінити *при каноні* стояв на *при гарматі / пушці* або *з гарматою / пушкою* стояв, то цілком підходить до контексту.

Answer (score 1):

Якщо врахувати, що це військова пісня, то можна пошукати серед слів специфічно військового вжитку. Маємо у [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53402/283426.html):

> **КАНОНІР**  (нім. Kanonier, від франц. **canon – гармата**) 
>   рядовий солдат артилерії в дореволюційній Росії.

Цікавить зауваження про французьке *канон - гармата*. Ліричний герой "фурт-фурт ладував", а це також говорить на користь припущення, що він був гармашем, відповідальним за заряд **гармати**.

Comment: Ще є [канонада](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40329&page=1274) (теж, здається, від _canon_).